# Flurry does not log anything in android

Tags: android, analytics, flurry

I have implemented flurry before. It was working fine. Today with new version of sdk, flurry does not log any thing in logcat.

My code

Flurry.java

```
public class Flurry {

private static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
private static Context mContext;

public static void init(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public static void onStartSession() {
    if (mContext != null) {
        Debug.e("", "startng flurry session...");

        FlurryAgent.setUserId(Utils.getUserId(mContext));
        FlurryAgent.setVersionName(Utils.getAppVersion(mContext));
        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(mContext, API_KEY);
        // FlurryAgent.initializeAds(mContext);
    } else {
        Debug.e("", "mContext is null");
    }
}

public static void onEndSession() {
    if (mContext != null) {
        Debug.e("", "ending flurry session...");
        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(mContext);
    }
}
}
```

in Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TabHost tabHost;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Flurry.init(this);
    Flurry.onStartSession();        

    setTabs();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Flurry.onEndSession();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

when I implemented before it show me log like this, but today implementing in another app, i did not get any log of flurry... what can be the issue??

```
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  Initializing Flurry session
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  New session
 4359          TitleActivity  V  ::onResume::
 4359               Settings  W  Setting android_id has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
 4359            FlurryAgent  I  loading persistent data: /data/data/com.xxxxxx/files/.flurryagent.-6ee7b2a3
  4359            FlurryAgent  D  Loading API key: ****************xxxx
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  Loading session reports
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  Persistent file loaded
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  generating report
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  Sending report to: http://data.flurry.com/aap.do
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  Report successful
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  Processing report response
 4359            FlurryAgent  D  Done sending initial agent report
```

Comment: I did not get any event or session on flurry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get log messages when using Flurry Analytics SDK v3.1.0 (created and downloaded this week from Flurry).

Here's the relevant code that configured Flurry to write messages to the Android log:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, FLURRY_API_KEY);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
}
```

And here is the evidence

```
01-10 11:35:23.310: I/FlurryAgent(3915): loading persistent data: /data/data/com.ader/files/.flurryagent.624f614c
01-10 11:35:23.310: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Loading API key: ****************RY7Z
01-10 11:35:23.320: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Loading phoneId: AND2001447e7dcd4d3b
01-10 11:35:23.320: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Loading session reports
01-10 11:35:23.320: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Session report added: 1
01-10 11:35:23.320: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Session report added: 2
01-10 11:35:23.320: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Persistent file loaded
01-10 11:35:23.560: D/FlurryAgent(3915): generating report
01-10 11:35:23.570: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Sending report to: http://data.flurry.com/aap.do
01-10 11:35:29.610: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Report successful
01-10 11:35:29.610: D/FlurryAgent(3915): Done sending initial agent report
```

I think the trick is the following call you don't have:

```
FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. I got event logged in next day in flurry and still it does not log into logcat..

Comment: Have you added the call to setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE)?   Also, try doing a clean build & uninstall your app before reinstalling it just to see if any gremlins are hiding in the build and deployment process.

Comment: Please can you also post the log generated when you run the app you have problems with. That should at least include: "startng flurry session..." so we know the call to onStartSession() occurs. And can you confirm which version of Flurry you're having problems with?

Comment: And as another suggestion, how about creating a new skeleton Activity and add the calls to Flurry in the onStart and onStop. Then modify your app to call the new activity and see if that convinces flurry to start logging.

Comment: D/FlurryAgent(7745): Attempting to persist AdLogs
D/FlurryAgent(7745): Attempting to persist FreqCap

i just get this log in logcat when i use the above method in onstart and onstop what i am doing wrong??

Comment: can we skip the line `FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);` so that i get all logs ?

Comment: @SweetWisherツ I don't know, perhaps the simplest and fastest way is for you to try. I'm not actively using Flurry at the moment and would have to create a project to determine what happens...

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
    FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    //System.out.println("Started Flurry");
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();     
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    //System.out.println("Stopped Flurry");
}
```

Comment: I know it's working but when you use `FlurryAgent` directly in Activity . I had created another Flurry util class which was not working. Because I think I was giving context through `init` method and I don't know why Flurry is having problem with `context`. Every developer is having complains of `context`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who will have same problem like me recently.

```
FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
// must be last one
FlurryAgent.init(context, "some key");
```

I was initializing Flurry in class that extends Application. It was important to have init call is last.

It is mentioned [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/technicalquickstart/android/), at the bottom of the page for 3 methods there are:

> ... This should be called before init.